# Curl POST issue with php

Tags: php, api, curl

I've got an sms server that works perfectly with a curl request like this one

```
curl -X POST http://local_IP/raspisms/api/scheduled/ -H 'X-Api-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' -d 'text=My%20Message' -d 'numbers=06XXXXXXXX'
```

I succeed in running a php code like this one

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://local_IP/raspisms/api/scheduled/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "text=My%Message&numbers=06XXXXXXXX");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I pass the message variable like this no problem

```
$text = "My Message";
define('POSTVARS', 'numbers=06XXXXXXXX&text=');  
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://local_IP/raspisms/api/scheduled/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POSTVARS.$text);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm stuck to pass both message and phone number variable. I already try the array() way

```
$data = array("text"=>$messages,
"numbers"=>$tel
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

seems correct to me, but doesn't work

I tried too

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "text={$message}&numbers={$tel}");
```

I try the variables with double quote `{\"text\":\"$message\"}`

Also tried this one `$url = 'http://api.pushingbox.com/pushingbox?devid=vB9C6311111098CB&sensor=' . $delta . '&temperature=' . $temp;`

I don't know what i can try to solve it (i don't receive any kind of error)

Comment: Your way of doing it with `http_build_query` is the way I would suggest to do it - just ensure that `$messages` and `$tel` are actually set with a value.

Comment: Both of them are set with a value 

Comment: check this "text=".$message."&numbers=".$tel

Comment: Thanks, already tested it too, it doesn't work. Is it possible to look with the define('POSTVARS', 'numbers=06XXXXXXXX&text='); way. I tried to define 2 variable and add them to the curl postfields. I got a php error saying it is waiting for 3 arguments and not 4. I saw one article on this subject. Nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was it cannot handle local phone number (06XXXXXXXX) but with international format no problem (+33), so variable has to start with "%2B33XXXXXXXX" and that works fine

Answer (score 0):

With `define('POSTVARS', 'text='.$text.'&numbers='.$tel);` i echo POSTVAR to get `text=MyMessage&numbers=06XXXXXXXX`

It looks like this solution is working but the api "refuses" it

Between `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POSTVARS);` which is refused and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "text=MyMessage&numbers=06XXXXXXXX");` which is sent, what's the difference ?